# How to modifiy Material-UI TextField input type Number

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

for now the `type = "number"` in TextFiled Material-UI
accept `number(0-9)` `coma (,)` and `double dash(--)`

and, I just need one `dash(-)`

I've seen to insert pattern in inputProps, but it seems not working..

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you

```
 <TextField
    label="Super Koin"
    variant="outlined"
    type="number"
    inputProps={{
       pattern: /^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/g
      }}
    name="Gajian"
    style={{ marginBottom: "22px" }}
    defaultValue={
        (form.injectCustomer && form.injectCustomer.supercoin) ||
            0
         }
     fullWidth
     inputRef={this.superPoints}
     InputLabelProps={{
         shrink: true
      }}
     onChange={e => {
                      
     this.actionRow(
     { key: "supercoin", value: (e.target.value)},
            "supercoin"
         );
       }}
     />
```

I'm trying to make validation inside `onChange`

```
 onChange={e => {
    console.log(e.target.value,"EEE")
    this.actionRow({ 
      key: "supercoin", 
      value: e.target.value === "--" ? e.target.value = 0 : e.target.value = 
     },
      "supercoin"
    );
                       
}}
```

but, the console.log for "-" and "--" is empty and it seems impossible to validate from `onChange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [react-number-format](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format) and provide a custom implementation of the `<input>` element with the `inputComponent` property:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

const NumberFormatCustom = React.forwardRef(function NumberFormatCustom(props, ref) {
  const { onChange, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <NumberFormat
      {...other}
      getInputRef={ref}
      onValueChange={(values) => {
        onChange({
          target: {
            name: props.name,
            value: values.value,
          },
        });
      }}
      // isNumericString
    />
  );
});

NumberFormatCustom.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default function FormattedInput() {
  const [numberformat, setNumberformat] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setNumberformat(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <TextField
        label="react-number-format"
        value={numberformat}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="numberformat"
        id="formatted-numberformat-input"
        InputProps={{
          inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
        }}
        variant="standard"
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit FormattedInputs Material Demo (forked)]

Answer (score 3):

I think when using patterns you have to use the `type="text"`.

Then add the `inputMode: 'numeric'` in your `inputProps`.

```js
<TextField 
    type="text" 
    inputProps={{ 
           inputMode: 'numeric', 
           pattern: '/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/g'
    }} 
/>
```

Comment: it's not working, and thank you for coming by, you may have another advice?

Comment: You have to add a style when the input is invalid `input:invalid {
  background-color: lightpink;
}`

Comment: @Fraction ahh I see, but do you have any advice so the user cant type anything but positive & negative number, instead coloring the text field ?

Comment: you could use a third-party library, see my answer

Comment: @Fraction one more question sir, when I input wrong it will changing color right, does it submitted (send payload) when I press submit or not ? I'm considering your answer though

Comment: if the `noValidate` property is not set on `form` then no, otherwise you should check the form validity on submit event(using `checkValidity()` for example) and do the necessary actions

Comment: NOTE: make sure its `inputProps` and not `InputProps`. First one accepts inputMode: numeric as it applies to DOM input. The second one doesnt as it applied to mui's input.

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={(evt) => {
  evt.stopPropagation()
  evt.preventDefault()
  evt.currentTarget.value = evt.target.value.replace(/[\D\s]/, '')
  return 
 }}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget